# Connection to remote Mysql database closing

Tags: java, mysql

I made a java app on my local machine which is connecting to a remote MySQL database, when I run on localhost it works OK, but on the remote connection after a few seconds without interaction it is losing the connection and brings

> No operation allowed after connection closed.

and

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQL.NonTransientConnectionException:No operation allowed after connection closed.

I have tried to remove con.close from my code but still the same.

How do I keep the connection alive until I close the app?

```
    private void jButton18ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton18ActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    String stkidreq = txtserchreq.getText();
    String pool = lblpool.getText();
    String dform = ((JTextField) jdaterfrom.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    String dto = ((JTextField) jdaterto.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    String rstatus = cmbstatus.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String exdate = ((JTextField) jdaterfrom.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();

    ((DefaultTableModel) tblreq.getModel()).setRowCount(0);

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblreq.getModel();

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        java.sql.Connection conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://so /so n so", "so so", "");
        Statement st = conn2.createStatement();
        String query = " select  r.request_id, r.shareholder_id, s.username, s.shareholder_fname, s.shareholder_lname, s.shareholder_phone, r.request_date, r.request_amount, r.pool, r.notes, r.req_status from requests r, shareholder s, saving_pool p where  r.shareholder_id = '" + stkidreq + "' and s.shareholder_id = '" + stkidreq + "' and p.Pool_name = '" + pool + "' and s.pool = '" + pool + "' and s.shareholder_id = r.shareholder_id and (r.request_date between '" + dform + "' and '" + dto + "') and r.req_status = '" + rstatus + "' order by r.request_date asc ";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String request_id = rs.getString("request_id");
            String shareholder_id = rs.getString("shareholder_id");
            String username = rs.getString("username");
            String shareholder_fname = rs.getString("shareholder_fname");
            String shareholder_lname = rs.getString("shareholder_lname");
            String shareholder_phone = rs.getString("shareholder_phone");
            String request_date = rs.getString("request_date");

            String request_amount = rs.getString("request_amount");
            String pool3 = rs.getString("pool");
            String notes = rs.getString("request_date");
            String req_status = rs.getString("req_status");

            model.addRow(new Object[]{request_id, shareholder_id, username, shareholder_fname, shareholder_lname, shareholder_phone, request_date, request_amount, pool3, notes, req_status});
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        conn2.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Comment: double check if you have allowed mysql remote connections. By default, I believe it's off.

Comment: is this a java application for the public or application for a selected (trusted) number of people?  Because it's not safe to hardcode MySQL username/password in java application which can be decompiled